# run bash script as root without su or password

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, restore, su

Can I create a bash script (as root) that will later run as root when called by a normal user without the presence of `su` or `sudo` present on the system and be capable of writing to a file in `/etc` or `/usr/bin`?

Last month someone got in to my colo servers and deleted the `sudoers` file, the root password and the `su` binaries from several of my clients machines.

I had to physically visit the machines and fix this with a rescue disk.  Annoyingly pricey.

Appears to be simply mischief and I've patched the security hole but it brought up the question of how to fix this as a normal user if there's no binaries for `su` or `sudo` on the system AND the references to root password have been removed from the password file.

I was hoping to run a script to restore back up files that had contents something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp sudoers.bak > /etc/sudoers
cp su /usr/bin/su
cp passwd.bak > /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Assuming "mischief" here is **incredibly** unwise. Restoring from clean backup on a new machine/installation is the right choice here. That said any script such as you are asking for would be a **gaping** security hole as it would allow non-root users on your system to do exactly this (with data they provide) and gain root access to your system.